# null pointer exception on calling interface method implemented in other class

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to call the method `getFailureDialog()` of the interface `OnSelectedListener`.
The method is implemented in `MainActivity.java`. But when I call the method, I am getting 
the null pointer exception.

I know that its because `OnSelectedListener` is still not initialized and you are calling `getFailureDialog()` on uninitialized object. Obviously, interface methods are never initialized. But then how do I call the method `getFailureDialog()` from my class `Common.java`?

I am placing only the relevant source code below-

Source code:

**SharedFragment.java**

```
public class SharedFragment extends DialogFragment 
{       
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    final String email = bundle.getString("email");

    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() {
        common.myRecord(email);
    }
    });   t.start(); 
}
```

**Common.java**

```
public class Common
{
OnSelectedListener mCallback;


    public interface OnSelectedListener 
    {
        public void getFailureDialog();
    }

    public void myRecord(String email)
    {
        mCallback.getFailureDialog();  //null pointer exception here
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity implements Common.OnSelectedListener
{

@Override
    public void getFailureDialog()
    {

        RecordFailure fd = new RecordFailure(); 
        fd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

**Error Log**

```
03-22 15:50:39.032: W/dalvikvm(20796): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4204c450)
03-22 15:50:39.052: E/AndroidRuntime(20796): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-30126
03-22 15:50:39.052: E/AndroidRuntime(20796): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-22 15:50:39.052: E/AndroidRuntime(20796):    at com.cornmail.util.Common.myRecord(Common.java:2062)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
OnSelectedListener mCallback;
```

is never getting initialized, or is being initialized with a null value.

```
public class Common
{
    OnSelectedListener mCallback = new OnSelectedListener(){
        public void getFailureDialog(){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An Error Has Occurred.");
        }
    };


    public interface OnSelectedListener 
    {
        public void getFailureDialog();
    }

    public void myRecord(String email)
    {
        mCallback.getFailureDialog();  //now this works.
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that's true but can you give me idea that its a interface and how to initialize it?

Comment: you cant initialize an interface, what a bad answer

Comment: @demongill sure you can. Just for example, you use new View.OnClickListener and ovveride the onClick() method. This is not the process of "initialization" in the common sense, but I think Kylar has just generalized that

Comment: i never found interface with design like this as my experience. interface should be implemented 1st in other class before it being used by another class

Comment: Then you don't have enough experience. Initializing anonymous interface implementations is very very common in Swing.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a simple implementation of the interface.

Comment: ok, i admit i lack of experience in swing cause i never had a reason to use interface like this.
could you give me a reason why i should design interface like this?
what is the pros and cons?

Comment: In Swing there are lots of times when you need a small on-off class that does something very specific, for a button, or specific combo box, etc. So you make a tiny anonymous class that does that and implements the Swing interface.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/android/gallery3d/ui/OnSelectedListener.java) is the source code for the `OnSelectedListener`. Since that is an interface, you have to initialize it using *new* and overriding the `onSelected()` method OR let your class implement this listener

Answer (score 0):

add a method in

```
public class Common
{
    OnSelectedListener mCallback;

    public void setOnSelectedListener(OnSelectedListener listener){
        mCallback = listener;
    }

    public interface OnSelectedListener 
    {
        public void getFailureDialog();
    }

    public void myRecord(String email)
    {
        mCallback.getFailureDialog();  //null pointer exception here
    }
}
```

now use the `setOnSelectedListener()` to initialize your listener

but from you code you might need to implement another listener in your `SharedFragment` too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to redesign your code man, make Common class implement `OnSelectedListener` interface. So separate `OnSelectedListener` as outer interface not as inner interface.

i will code it like this.

```
public interface OnSelectedListener 
{
    public void getFailureDialog();
}
```

then `Common` class should be like this

```
public class Common implements OnSelectedListener
{
    public void getFailureDialog()
    {
        RecordFailure fd = new RecordFailure(); 
        fd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    public void myRecord(String email)
    {
        getFailureDialog();
        //do something more rather than just call existing method
    }
}
```

and this code will run smoothly.
if you need to implement the getFailureDialog in MainActivity, make this Common class as abstract class.

Common class will be like this

```
public abstract class Common implements OnSelectedListener
{
    public abstract void getFailureDialog();

    public void myRecord(String email)
    {
        getFailureDialog();
        //do something more rather than just call existing method
    }
}
```

now your `MainActivity` class can extend from this class to implement the missing part.

Comment: I agree with you but there must be some way to call interface method which is implemented in some other class with the object name in our class so that when I do object.method() it will not give null pointer.

Comment: Common class is the class that contains around 2000 lines of code with lots of implemented methods. It can't be abstract.

Comment: lets wait for other answer then, cause i would design my code like this. Why do u have to design such a mechanism like this? Is there existing API Library that coded like this, give me some point. I'll love to do some research.

Abstract class can have implemented method in it, but it can be instantiated. Have you ever use abstract class before?

Comment: the main idea to use such mechanism is that - there are lots of interfaces throughout the application with only few methods. So its awkward to create class for every interface having such a small code. Putting it inside a class is the better idea and was recommended.

Comment: the other reason is - I have all the implemented methods of every interface in a single class which is MainActivity.java so that it is easy to know that the implemented methods belong to this class and you don't have to search every time that where is the implementation of any method of interface.

Comment: IMHO you do so many bad design on your application. Do you learn some pattern that implicate interface in it, e.g factory pattern or adapter pattern? What is the point we should use an interface, it because it polymorphism, do some research how this pattern work and this will make you better on how you design your application.

Also for case interface with small code why do you need such an interface for this? why don't u just use abstract, interface shouldn't be treat like that.
maybe we just have different comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify Common and MainActivity. In Common add a basic constructor. Then activate the callback as shown in startMyCallback.

Common.java

```
public class Common
{

 public Common() {}

 OnSelectedListener mCallback;


 public interface OnSelectedListener 
 {
    public void getFailureDialog();
 }

 public void myRecord(String email)
 {
    mCallback.getFailureDialog();  //null pointer exception here
 }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity implements Common.OnSelectedListener
{

    Common common = new Common();

    public MainActivity()
    {

    }

    public void startMyCallback()
    {
        common.mCallback = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void getFailureDialog()
    {
        RecordFailure fd = new RecordFailure(); 
        fd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```