# IllegalStateException passing data between fragments

Tags: java, android, interface, fragment, illegalstateexception

EDIT: Finally fixed it. To fix the IllegalStateException I added a OnClickListener instead of onClick xml, as the problem was that the Function the button called was in the Fragment, not in the parent activity itself.
After that, I had a nullPointerException. This helped me out: [null pointer exception on calling interface method implemented in other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568234/null-pointer-exception-on-calling-interface-method-implemented-in-other-class)
I hope this is useful for someone :)

I'm creating an app where I have an Activity and to Fragments which are shown as tabs (I'm using SherlockActionBar). I have created a button, which calls a function on the Activity (using xml onClick), and that function calls a public function on one of the tabs.
I'm using an interface to send data between the tabs.

I have used this tutorial as an example: http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/
I have downloaded its source code, but I do not understand how it differs from mine, why that one does work while mine doesn't

My code is as follows:

Interface:

```java
package es.pabloarteaga.vocabulario;

public interface ForgottenListener {

public void addWord(String word, String other);

}
```

Main activity: (oFRAG1 and oFRAG2 are the fragments which are shown in the tabs)

```java
public class Quiz1 extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ForgottenListener {

ViewPager oPAGER;
Tab oTAB;
ActionBar oBARRA;
Quiz1main oFRAG1 = new Quiz1main();
Quiz1remember oFRAG2 = new Quiz1remember();

public void dbgfnc(View v) {
oFRAG1.addForgottenWord ("aaa","BBB");
}

@Override 
Public void addWord (String word, String other) {
//Still does nothing
}
```

Fragment where function the function is called:

```java
public class Quiz1main extends SherlockFragment {
ForgottenListener oLISTEN;

public void addForgottenWord(String word, String Other) {
    oLISTEN.addWord("AAA", "BBB");
}

}
```

Exception log:

```
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3735)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4354)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17961)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3730)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    ... 11 more
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at es.pabloarteaga.vocabulario.Quiz1main.addForgottenWord(Quiz1main.java:43)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    at es.pabloarteaga.vocabulario.Quiz1.dbgfnc(Quiz1.java:30)
08-21 00:03:55.192: E/AndroidRuntime(28264):    ... 14 more
```

Comment: you have implemented `ForgottenListener` in `MainActivity`, but did you implement `public void addWord(String word, String other){}` also inside MainActivity?

Comment: Yes, I did. Sorry for not including that. Will edit the question now :) Thank you very much